# How to export AWS API Gateway REST API to a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I've created my own API on AWS API Gateway and U want to export it to a file , how can we do that ?

[image]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you export your API you will need to ensure that you have [deployed your API to a stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html), as you will need to export from this.

Once this is done it can be exported very simply, following the below instructions:

- Click the stages link
- Click on the stage you're using
- Click the `Export` tab
- Select whether to export as `Swagger` or `OpenAPI 3`
- Select the `Export as  Swagger/OpenAPI 3 with API Gateway Extensions` and click either `JSON` or `YAML`

For more information check out the [How do I migrate API Gateway APIs between AWS accounts or Regions?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-migrate-accounts-regions/) page.

Comment: You will also need to publish the documentation otherwise this won't be included in the exported definition.